# How to sort text columns in a specific manner?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I was wondering if it was possible to have a way to sort text rows in a specific manner. What I mean by that is, imagine we have a column of 15 rows which could contain :

```
Foo 
Bar
Something
Other_example
```

We want to be able to sort them in this particular order. The easy option I found was to put numbers in front of them (`1 - Foo`, `2 - Bar`, etc) and then sorting them in a normal (alphanumerical) manner, but that is not really visually appealing, I would say.

Is there another way to do it simply ? For example by "hiding" the numbers, or something else ? Of course I could write a script for it with with a condition such as a switch-case, but that wouldn't be truly what I am looking for and easily done within the spreadsheet itself (I think so at least, I have never really gone far in sheets possibilities). However if there is no other option, I will do it and add a simple button to access the script, I guess.

Thank for your time !

Sanimys

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(IFERROR(
 VLOOKUP(C2:C, {A2:A, ROW(A2:A)}, {1, 2}, 0)), 2, 1), 999^99, 1))
```

[image: 0]